# Have nautilus open file into new gvim buffer?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, editor, vim

Is there a way to configure nautilus to open a file into an existing gvim process in a new buffer instead of loading a new instance of gvim?  I know I can drag and drop the file into gvim, but it would be convenient if I could just double-click a file to open it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In a Terminal

```
cd ~/.local/share/applications
vi gvim-tab.desktop
```

Copy Paste this code :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=GVim Text Editor (Tabs)
Comment=Edit text files in a new tab
Exec=gvim --remote-tab %F
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/vim.svg
Categories=Application;Utility;TextEditor;
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/plain;
NoDisplay=true
```

In Nautilus

```
Right-Click in a text file
Open With
Open with a another application
Select "GVim Text Editor (Tabs)"
```

It's done

Comment: Awesome -- exactly what I was trying to figure out!  Thank you! :D

Comment: This works really well for me, except that with the configuration above my cursor changed to a spinner for a very long time.  To fix it I changed `StartupNotify=false` in the desktop entry. http://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/startup-notification.html.en

Comment: Excellent. Combined with an alias for when opening things from a terminal, and live is better now. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to do the exact same thing but with split windows instead of tabs?

Comment: Use `Exec=bash -c "gvim --remote-tab %F || gvim"`, and you can just override the default `gvim.desktop` file (by renaming the one in `~/.local/share/applications` to `gvim.desktop` instead of `gvim-tab.desktop`.) This way you get the new tab functionality without a new icon in your dash, and without having to re-associate all your filetypes.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. I missed the `NoDisplay` key in the answer -- it wouldn't add a new dash icon after all.

Comment: love this, exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 3):

You're really just wanting to launch gVim with the --remote-tab-silent option. From [the manual](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/remote.html#--remote-silent):-

```
                            *--remote-tab-silent*
   --remote-tab-silent
   Like --remote-silent but open each file in a new tabpage.
```

Also just check out --remote-silent if you're not wanting a new tab and want to create a new buffer.

Comment: Any idea where gnome configures which program is associated with text files?  System -> Preferences -> Preferred Applications seems to be the right area, but it doesn't allow you to pick a text editor there . . .

Comment: I'm on a mac so I'm not 100%, but you could try this :- http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/add-open-with-gedit-to-the-right-click-menu-in-ubuntu/ and use this script instead:- http://pastebin.com/m7abf308e It might do the trick.